# New Ubuntu 14.04 installation with full disk encryption prompts for passphrase in console

Tags: boot, encryption, prompt

My previous Ubuntu 14.04 installation launched to a graphical screen with the Ubuntu logo and a text prompt under it for passphrase insertion. I did a distro upgrade, which broke my installation, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04. Now I have to enter the passphrase in a console when I boot up my PC, even though I set up the disk partitions and encryption exactly as before.

Any idea?